# Von-Neumann vs Bernoulli Utility? Do properties of Bernoulli translate to VNM?

Tags: microeconomics, uncertainty

This is for a HW question but I am not asking on how to solve the question, just a conceptual question.

According to my understanding,

1. A Von-Neumann Utility function represents preferences over lotteries of monetary outcomes.
2. A Bernoulli utility function represents preferences over sure amounts of money.

My homework question asks me to consider a VNM utility function and asks me to find restrictions on parameters for it to display risk aversion. I think this should say Bernoulli function instead.

All the definitions in MWG are defined in the context of Bernoulli not VNM i.e. Bernoulli utility needs to be concave ($u'(.)> 0$ and $u''(.)< 0$). But can I apply this definition to VNM and proceed the same way to find these restrictions, i.e. if Bernoulli is concave then VNM is concave and so I can find the restrictions same way?

Comment: Just a question: where did you read that Bernoulli utility is defined over sure amounts of money? A very nice book on utility functions and related concepts is written by Christian Gollier "The Economics of Risk and Time, 2001", it helped me a lot to understand the basic concepts. Perhaps it will help you to find the answers 

Comment: @T123 MWG pg 184 confirms this. Thanks for your suggestion. I' ll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminology is not uniform; many authors call Bernoulli utility functions von Neumann - Morgenstern utility functions or just utility functions.

Expected utility is linear in lotteries and, therefore, trivially weakly concave if one interprets lotteries as elements of a suitable vector space.

Unless the function for which you should check parameters is a linear function of lotteries, it is probably supposed to represent a Bernoulli function and you can check for which parameters it is concave.

Comment: MWG places an emphasis on making that distinction, but I buy your vector space argument. Thanks!